# Laravel database access denied

Tags: laravel, homestead

I am new to Laravel and am getting an error when trying to run a simple command in the controller `Article::all()`.  The error is:

> PDOException in Connector.php line 55:
>   SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Here is my `.env` file:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=v1xavEadi4rHv0EGn05zQvtVAtQRA9zo

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

The controller:

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use App\Article;

class ArticlesController extends Controller
{
    public function index() 
    {

        $articles = Article::all();
    }
}
```

and the model:

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Article extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [

        'name',
        'body'

    ];
}
```

Comment: the default database logins for homestead is "User: homestead / Pass: secret"

Comment: @Prashank - this might be really stupid...but didn't I modify the default pass and login in the ".env" file?

Comment: Have you edited the database file in config folder?

Comment: @TimvanUum no I didn't make any modifications to the config database file.  It's set up for mysql however " 'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql')".   I have also done a few migrations that worked just fine connecting to the database.

Comment: @Tim van Uum could you write it as an answer so this question can be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyone else looking at this in the future with the same issue - restart the command prompt after changing the env file in windows.  Restarting the server didn't work, but closing out of everything and then trying it again worked.

Comment: Dude, thanks for figuring that out. I kept refreshing the page and the server, but it wouldn't make a difference. restarting the command line did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Homestead with the default database credentials, then you have to edit your `.env` file:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=test
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Though it's recommended to change the default password.