# laravel QueryException line 770

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, xampp

I have a problem when I want to register in laravel. After completing the registration form I see this error message:

> QueryException in Connection.php line 770:
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` =

thank you for helping me.

Comment: Do you have your connection set up in the `.env` or `config/database.php` files?

Comment: Have you configured the `DB` properties in your `.env` file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel database access denied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33973442/laravel-database-access-denied)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create DB and add information in /.env file

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=YOUR_DB_NAME
DB_USERNAME=YOUR_DB_USER_NAME
DB_PASSWORD=YOUR_DB_USER_PASSWORD
```